# Why can't the pseudosphere be completed in $R^3$?

Tags: soft-question, surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Without appealing to Hilbert's theorem on the non-embeddability of complete hyperbolic surfaces in $R^3$, is there a way to "see" that one can't extend the pseudosphere / surface of revolution of a tractrix to a complete surface in $R^3$?

I mean, it is clear from the construction of the tractrix as the involute of a caternary that one cannot just keep going using the original construction, but I don't really see why it is impossible in principle. In what sense does one run out of room? From the picture of a pseudo-sphere it seems like one runs out of angle, if that makes sense.

Comment: There might not be a simpler proof known than Hilbert's proof. The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_theorem_(differential_geometry) gives a proof sketch which is "basically the same as in Hilbert's paper, although based in the books of Do Carmo and Spivak".

Comment: the problem is not that a tracioid cannot be constructed (which is indeed possible) the problem is that a tracioid cannot be extended so that the complete hyperbolic plane is on it.